# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I got a piece of code that keeps returning NULL.

```
public function load_network_settings()
        {
            $db = &$this->db1;
            $r  = $db->query('SELECT * FROM settings', FALSE);
            while($obj = $db->fetch_object($r)) {
                $this->C->{$obj->word}  = stripslashes($obj->value);
            }

            global $C;
            foreach($this->C as $k=>$v) {
                $C->$k  = & $this->C->$k;
            }

            if( !isset($C->SITE_TITLE) || empty($C->SITE_TITLE) ) {
                $C->SITE_TITLE  = 'Friendly';
            }
            $C->OUTSIDE_SITE_TITLE  = $C->SITE_TITLE;
        }
```

To be exact, it's this line

```
$r  = $db->query('SELECT * FROM settings', FALSE);
```

I don't think it's connecting to the database properly either, but I don't really understand what is happening.

**class_network.php**

```
<?php

    class network
    {
        public $id;
        public $info;
        public $is_private;
        public $is_public;
        public $mysql;

        public function __construct()
        {   
            $this->id   = FALSE;
            $this->C    = new stdClass;
            $this->info = new stdClass;
            $this->db1      = & $GLOBALS['db1'];
            $this->db2      = & $GLOBALS['db2'];
            $this->mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','SCM') or die ("problem");
        }

        public function load()
        {
            if( $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $this->load_network_settings();
            $this->info = (object) array(
                'id'    => 1,
            );
            $this->is_private   = FALSE;
            $this->is_public    = TRUE;
            $this->id   = $this->info->id;
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function load_network_settings()
        {
            $db = &$this->db1;
            $r  = $db->query('SELECT * FROM settings', FALSE);
            while($obj = $db->fetch_object($r)) {
                $this->C->{$obj->word}  = stripslashes($obj->value);
            }

            global $C;
            foreach($this->C as $k=>$v) {
                $C->$k  = & $this->C->$k;
            }

            if( !isset($C->SITE_TITLE) || empty($C->SITE_TITLE) ) {
                $C->SITE_TITLE  = 'Friendly';
            }
            $C->OUTSIDE_SITE_TITLE  = $C->SITE_TITLE;
        }

        public function get_user_by_username($uname, $force_refresh=FALSE, $return_id=FALSE)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            if( empty($uname) ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            $uid    = FALSE;
            $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT iduser FROM users WHERE username="'.$this->db2->e($uname).'" LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if( $o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r) ) {
                $uid    = intval($o->iduser);
                return $return_id ? $uid : $this->get_user_by_id($uid);
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        public function get_user_by_email($email, $force_refresh=FALSE, $return_id=FALSE)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            if( ! is_valid_email($email) ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            $uid    = FALSE;
            $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT iduser FROM users WHERE email="'.$this->db2->escape($email).'" LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if( $o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r) ) {
                $uid    = intval($o->iduser);
                return $return_id ? $uid : $this->get_user_by_id($uid);
            }

            return FALSE;
        }

        public function get_user_by_id($uid, $force_refresh=FALSE)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $uid    = intval($uid);
            if( 0 == $uid ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE iduser="'.$uid.'" LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if ($o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r)) {
                $o->active      = intval($o->active);
                $o->firstname   = stripslashes($o->firstname);
                $o->lastname    = stripslashes($o->lastname);
                $o->aboutme = stripslashes($o->aboutme);
                $o->codecountry = stripslashes($o->codecountry);
                $o->city    = stripslashes($o->city);
                $o->idregion    = intval($o->idregion);
                $o->network_id  = $this->id;
                $o->user_details    = FALSE;
                return $o;
            }

            return FALSE;
        }

        public function get_page_by_url($url, $return_id=FALSE)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) return FALSE;
            if( empty($url) ) return FALSE;

            $uid = FALSE;
            $r = $this->db2->query('SELECT idpage FROM pages WHERE url="'.$this->db2->e($url).'" LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if( $o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r) ) {
                $uid    = intval($o->idpage);
                return $return_id ? $uid : $this->get_page_by_id($uid);
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        public function get_page_by_id($idpage)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $idpage = intval($idpage);
            if (0 == $idpage) return FALSE;

            $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE idpage='.$idpage.' LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if ($o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r)) {
                $o->status  = intval($o->status);
                $o->title   = stripslashes($o->title);
                $o->url = $o->url;
                $o->idpage  = intval($o->idpage);
                $o->code    = $o->code;
                return $o;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        public function get_group_by_url($url, $return_id=FALSE)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) return FALSE;
            if( empty($url) ) return FALSE;

            $uid = FALSE;
            $r = $this->db2->query('SELECT idgroup FROM groups WHERE url="'.$this->db2->e($url).'" LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if( $o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r) ) {
                $uid    = intval($o->idgroup);
                return $return_id ? $uid : $this->get_group_by_id($uid);
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        public function get_group_by_id($idgroup)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) return FALSE;

            $idgroup    = intval($idgroup);
            if (0 == $idgroup) return FALSE;

            $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT * FROM groups WHERE idgroup='.$idgroup.' LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if ($o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r)) {
                $o->status = intval($o->status);
                $o->name_group = stripslashes($o->name_group);
                $o->url = $o->url;
                $o->idgroup = intval($o->idgroup);
                $o->code    = $o->code;
                return $o;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        public function get_ads_basic($code)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT adsource FROM ads_basic WHERE code="'.$code.'" LIMIT 1');
        }

        // Check if $uid1 is a follower of $uid2
        public function verifies_follower($uid1, $uid2)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $uid1 = intval($uid1);
            if( 0 == $uid1 ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            $uid2 = intval($uid2);
            if( 0 == $uid2 ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idrelation FROM relations WHERE leader='.$uid2.' AND type_leader=0 AND subscriber='.$uid1);
        }

        public function get_user_follows($uid, $type = FALSE)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $uid = intval($uid);
            if( 0 == $uid ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            $data = new stdClass;
            $data->followers = array();
            $data->follow_users = array();

            if( ($type && $type == 'hisfollowers') || ($type === FALSE) ){
                $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT suscriber FROM relations WHERE leader="'.$uid.'" AND type_leader=0 ORDER BY idrelation DESC', FALSE);
                while($o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r)) {
                    $data->followers[intval($o->suscriber)] = 1;
                }
            }
            if( ($type && $type == 'hefollows') || ($type === FALSE) ){
                $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT leader FROM relations WHERE suscriber="'.$uid.'" AND type_leader=0 ORDER BY idrelation DESC', FALSE);
                while($o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r)) {
                    $data->follow_users[intval($o->leader)] = 2;
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }

        public function get_country($codecountry)
        {
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT country FROM country WHERE code="'.$codecountry.'" LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function get_region($idregion)
        {
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT region FROM country_region WHERE idregion='.$idregion.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function isUserVerified($uid)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $uid = intval($uid);
            if( 0 == $uid ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            $r  = $this->db2->query('SELECT verified FROM users WHERE iduser="'.$uid.'" LIMIT 1', FALSE);
            if ($o = $this->db2->fetch_object($r)) {
                if ($o->verified==1) return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }

        public function getUserAleat($total, $exclude=0, $privacy=-1)
        {
            global $user;
            $condition = '';
            if ($user->is_logged) {
                $friends = $this->db2->fetch_all('SELECT iduser FROM friends, users WHERE accepted<>0 AND ((user1=iduser AND user2='.$user->id.') OR (user1='.$user->id.' AND user2=iduser))');

                if (count($friends)>0) {
                    $arrayFriends = array();
                    foreach($friends as $onefriend) {
                        $arrayFriends[] = $onefriend->iduser;
                    }
                    $condition = ' iduser NOT IN ('.implode(',',$arrayFriends).') AND ';
                }
            }
            if ($privacy==-1) $r = $this->db2->fetch_all('SELECT * FROM users WHERE '.$condition.' active=1 AND iduser<>'.$exclude.' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT '.$total);
            else $r = $this->db2->fetch_all('SELECT * FROM users WHERE '.$condition.' active=1 AND privacy='.$privacy.' AND iduser<>'.$exclude.' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT '.$total);
            return $r;
        }

        public function getPostsUser($iduser)
        {
            $r = $this->db2->fetch_all('SELECT idpost, code FROM posts WHERE iduser='.$iduser);
            return $r;
        }


        public function getCodePost($idp)
        {
            $idp = intval($idp);
            if( 0 == $idp ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT code FROM posts WHERE idpost='.$idp.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getURLPage($idpage)
        {
            $idpage = intval($idpage);
            if( 0 == $idpage ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT url FROM pages WHERE idpage='.$idpage.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getURLGroup($idgroup)
        {
            $idgroup = intval($idgroup);
            if( 0 == $idgroup ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT url FROM groups WHERE idgroup='.$idgroup.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getCodeGroup($idgroup)
        {
            $idgroup = intval($idgroup);
            if( 0 == $idgroup ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT code FROM groups WHERE idgroup='.$idgroup.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getInfoGroup($idgroup)
        {
            $idgroup = intval($idgroup);
            if( 0 == $idgroup ) return FALSE;
            $r = $this->db2->fetch('SELECT url, name_group FROM groups WHERE idgroup='.$idgroup.' LIMIT 1');
            return $r;
        }

        public function verifiedPost($code, $idu)
        {
            $code = $this->db2->e($code);
            if (strlen($code) != 11) return FALSE;
            $idu = intval($idu);
            if( 0 == $idu ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idpost FROM posts WHERE code="'.$code.'" AND iduser='.$idu.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function verifiedPostinPage($code, $idpage)
        {
            $code = $this->db2->e($code);
            if (strlen($code) != 11) return FALSE;
            $idpage = intval($idpage);
            if( 0 == $idpage ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idpost FROM posts WHERE code="'.$code.'" AND posted_in=1 AND id_wall='.$idpage.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function verifiedPostinGroup($code, $idgroup)
        {
            $code = $this->db2->e($code);
            if (strlen($code) != 11) return FALSE;
            $idgroup = intval($idgroup);
            if( 0 == $idgroup ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idpost FROM posts WHERE code="'.$code.'" AND posted_in=2 AND id_wall='.$idgroup.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function idwall($code, $type)
        {
            $code = $this->db2->e($code);
            if (strlen($code) != 11) return FALSE;
            switch ($type) {
                case 0:
                    return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT iduser FROM users WHERE code="'.$code.'" LIMIT 1');
                    break;
                case 1:
                    return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idpage FROM pages WHERE code="'.$code.'" LIMIT 1');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idgroup FROM groups WHERE code="'.$code.'" LIMIT 1');
                    break;
            }
        }

        public function infoBasicWall($posted_in, $id_wall)
        {
            switch ($posted_in) {
                case 0:
                    $r = $this->db2->fetch('SELECT code, username, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE iduser='.$id_wall.' LIMIT 1');
                    break;  
                case 1:
                    $r = $this->db2->fetch('SELECT code, url, title, idpage FROM pages WHERE idpage='.$id_wall.' LIMIT 1');
                    break;  
                case 2:
                    $r = $this->db2->fetch('SELECT idgroup, code, url, name_group FROM groups WHERE idgroup='.$id_wall.' LIMIT 1');
                    break;  
            }
            return $r;          
        }

        public function getComment($idc)
        {
            $idc = intval($idc);
            if( 0 == $idc ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE idcomment='.$idc.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getInfoCommentById($idc)
        {
            $idc = intval($idc);
            if( 0 == $idc ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch('SELECT posts.code, posts.iduser, comment, username FROM comments, posts, users  WHERE users.iduser=posts.iduser AND comments.idpost=posts.idpost AND idcomment='.$idc.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getUsername($idu)
        {
            $idu = intval($idu);
            if( 0 == $idu ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT username FROM users WHERE iduser='.$idu.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getNumNotifications($idu)
        {
            $idu = intval($idu);
            if( 0 == $idu ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT num_notifications FROM users WHERE iduser='.$idu.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getNameCatPage($idcat)
        {
            $idcat = intval($idcat);
            if( 0 == $idcat ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT name FROM pages_cat WHERE idcategory='.$idcat.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function getUsersAleatHome($quantity=8)
        {
            //$r = $this->db2->fetch_all("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active=1 AND avatar<>'' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$quantity);
            $r = $this->db2->fetch_all("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$quantity);
            return $r;          
        }   


        public function getTrendsTopic($quantity=10)
        {
            global $C;
            $timenow = time();
            $timeoneday = time() - 86400000 * $C->NUM_DAYS_TRENDS;
            $r = $this->db2->fetch_all("SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT iduser ) total, trend FROM trends WHERE whendate < '".$timenow."' AND whendate > '".$timeoneday."' && trend <> '' GROUP BY trend ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT ".$quantity);
            return $r;          
        }

        // Check if $uid1 is a friend of $uid2
        public function verifyFriendship($uid1, $uid2, $action)
        {
            if( ! $this->id ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $uid1 = intval($uid1);
            $uid2 = intval($uid2);
            if( 0 == $uid1 || 0 == $uid2 ) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            switch ($action) {
                case 1:
                    return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT id FROM friends WHERE (user1='.$uid2.' AND user2='.$uid1.') OR (user1='.$uid1.' AND user2='.$uid2.')');
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT id FROM friends WHERE accepted=0 AND ((user1='.$uid2.' AND user2='.$uid1.') OR (user1='.$uid1.' AND user2='.$uid2.'))');
                    break;
                case 5:
                    return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT id FROM friends WHERE accepted<>0 AND ((user1='.$uid2.' AND user2='.$uid1.') OR (user1='.$uid1.' AND user2='.$uid2.'))');
                    break;
            }
        }

        public function idOwnerPost($idpost)
        {
            $idp = intval($idpost);
            if( 0 == $idp ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT iduser FROM posts WHERE idpost='.$idp.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function PostLiketoUser($iduser, $idpost)
        {
            $r  = $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idlike FROM likes WHERE iduser='.$iduser.' AND idpost='.$idpost.' LIMIT 1');
            return $r;
        }

        public function getCommentsPost($start, $quantity, $idpost, $iduhidden=0)
        {
            $sqlCommentsHiddens = '';
            if ($iduhidden != 0) {
                $sqlCommentsHiddens = ' SELECT iditem FROM hiddens WHERE typeitem=2 AND iduser='.$iduhidden;
                $sqlCommentsHiddens = ' idcomment NOT IN ('.$sqlCommentsHiddens.') AND ';
            }

            $r = $this->db2->fetch_all('
            SELECT idcomment, comments.whendate, comment, comments.iduser, username, firstname, lastname, avatar, idpost, users.code as ucode 
            FROM comments, users 
            WHERE '.$sqlCommentsHiddens.'
            users.iduser=comments.iduser 
            AND idpost='.$idpost.' 
            ORDER BY comments.whendate DESC 
            LIMIT '.$start.','.$quantity);
            return $r;
        }

        public function getNumCommentsPost($idpost, $iduhidden=0)
        {
            $sqlCommentsHiddens = '';
            if ($iduhidden != 0) {
                $sqlCommentsHiddens = ' SELECT iditem FROM hiddens WHERE typeitem=2 AND iduser='.$iduhidden;
                $sqlCommentsHiddens = ' idcomment NOT IN ('.$sqlCommentsHiddens.') AND ';
            }

            $r = $this->db2->fetch_field('
            SELECT count(idcomment) 
            FROM comments 
            WHERE '.$sqlCommentsHiddens.'
            idpost='.$idpost);
            return $r;
        }

        public function idOwnerPage($idpage)
        {
            $idp = intval($idpage);
            if( 0 == $idp ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idowner FROM pages WHERE idpage='.$idp.' LIMIT 1');
        }

        public function idOwnerGroup($idgroup)
        {
            $idg = intval($idgroup);
            if( 0 == $idg ) return FALSE;
            return $this->db2->fetch_field('SELECT idcreator FROM groups WHERE idgroup='.$idg.' LIMIT 1');
        }


    }

?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
/** 
 * 
 * NOTE: Designed for use with PHP version 4, 5 and up
 * @author Santos Montano B. <ssmontano@hotmail.com, litosantosm@gmail.com>
 * @country Perú
 * @copyright 2016
 * @version: 1.5.3
 * 
 */

/** 
 * Configuration file.
 */

    $C  = new stdClass;

    $C->INCPATH = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
    chdir( $C->INCPATH );

    $C->SITE_URL = 'http://localhost/';
    $C->DOMAIN = 'http://localhost';

    // MySQL SETTINGS
    $C->DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $C->DB_USER = 'root';
    $C->DB_PASS = '';
    $C->DB_NAME = 'SCM';
    $C->DB_MYEXT = 'mysql'; // 'mysqli' or 'mysql'  


    // Folder of user data
    $C->FOLDER_DATA = "data/";

    // Temporary folder
    $C->FOLDER_TMP = "data/tmp/";

    // Avatars folder users
    $C->FOLDER_AVATAR = "data/avatars/";    
    $C->AVATAR_DEFAULT = 'default.jpg';

    // Avatars folder pages
    $C->FOLDER_AVATAR_PAGES = "data/avatars_pages/";    
    $C->AVATAR_DEFAULT_PAGE = 'default.jpg';

    // Avatars folder groups
    $C->FOLDER_AVATAR_GROUPS = "data/avatars_groups/";  
    $C->AVATAR_DEFAUL_GROUP = 'default.jpg';    

    // Sizes for the avatar
    $C->widthAvatar0 = 180;
    $C->widthAvatar1 = 100;
    $C->heightAvatar1 = 100;
    $C->widthAvatar2 = 50;
    $C->heightAvatar2 = 50;
    $C->widthAvatar3 = 26;
    $C->heightAvatar3 = 26; 
    $C->widthAvatar4 = 180;
    $C->heightAvatar4 = 180;

    $C->SIZE_IMAGEN_AVATAR = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB;

    // photos folder users
    $C->FOLDER_PHOTOS = "data/photos/";

    // photos folder pages
    $C->FOLDER_PHOTOS_PAGES = "data/photos_pages/";

    // photos folder groups
    $C->FOLDER_PHOTOS_GROUPS = "data/photos_groups/";

    $C->SIZE_PHOTO = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB;

    // Sizes for the photos
    $C->widthPhotoThumbail = 230;

    /**************************/
    /**************************/

    // Covers folder users
    $C->FOLDER_COVERS = "data/covers/";

    // Covers folder pages
    $C->FOLDER_COVERS_PAGES = "data/covers_pages/";

    // Covers folder groups
    $C->FOLDER_COVERS_GROUPS = "data/covers_groups/";

    // Sizes for the covers
    $C->widthCover1 = 946;
    $C->heightCover1 = 300;
    $C->widthCover2 = 712;
    $C->heightCover2 = 226;
    $C->widthCover3 = 350;
    $C->heightCover3 = 111;


    $C->SIZE_IMAGEN_COVER = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB;

    /**************************/

    // Background folder of images in home
    $C->FOLDER_BGHOME = "data/bghome/";

    /**************************/

    // Images of Ads of users
    $C->FOLDER_ADS = "data/ads/";

    /**************************/

    // Albums of users
    $C->FOLDER_ALBUMS = "data/albums/";

    /**************************/

    //if you want to view page view statistics in administration section set the value to TRUE,
    $C->write_page_view_is_active   = FALSE;


    $C->LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK = TRUE;
    $C->FB_APPID = '111100001111000';
    $C->FB_SECRET = '44445555666677778888999900000000';

    $C->LOGIN_WITH_TWITTER = TRUE;
    $C->TW_APPID = 'xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyyxxxxyyyyx';
    $C->TW_SECRET = 'aaaabbbbaaaabbbbaaaabbbbaaaabbbbaaaabbbbaaabbbbaa';
    $C->DOMAIN_EMAIL_TW = 'kanorika.com'; //usually your domain

    // Settings for Mail
    $C->FromName = 'Friendly';
    $C->From = 'no-reply@kanorika.com';
    $C->Host = 'mail.kanorika.com';
    $C->Port = '587';
    $C->UsernameMail = 'no-reply@kanorika.com';
    $C->PasswordMail = 'yourpass';


    $C->INFINITE_SCROLL = TRUE;

    /*** VERSION 1.2 ***/

    $C->widthAd1 = 180;
    $C->heightAd1 = 90;

    $C->widthAd2 = 100;
    $C->heightAd2 = 50;

    /*** END VERSION 1.2 ***/

    /*** VERSION 1.3 ***/

    $C->LOGIN_WITH_VK = TRUE;
    $C->VK_APPID = '1111111';
    $C->VK_SECRET = 'xxxxdddxxxdddaaawwwsss';
    $C->DOMAIN_EMAIL_VK = 'kanorika.com'; //usually your domain

    $C->SHOW_APP = TRUE; // Show "images link" for download your app android

    /*** END VERSION 1.3 ***/

    /*** VERSION 1.4 ***/

    $C->LOGIN_WITH_GPLUS = TRUE;
    $C->GP_CLIENTID = '1122112211221-qvd3f4d3f4s2d3f4g5h6j7t5r4w2e3r4.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $C->GP_CLIENTSECRET = 'r4t5y6u7i8o9e3r4t5y6e3r4';

    $C->LOGIN_WITH_LINKEDIN = TRUE;
    $C->IN_APIKEY = '77defrg5h6e3r4';
    $C->IN_SECRETKEY = 'E343ere3r4r4r4r4';
    $C->DOMAIN_EMAIL_IN = 'kanorika.com'; //usually your domain

    $C->LOGIN_WITH_YAHOO = TRUE;
    $C->YH_CONSUMERKEY = 'dj0defrgthyswdefrgthyjukiloswdefrgtdefrgthyewdsewrefdregftrewdsewrefdretrgfwdsewdsrefdrer--';
    $C->YH_CONSUMERSECRET = '3329fwget4y5dsewfdredsew3243re4354tr32ew';
    $C->YH_DOMAIN_MAIN = 'www.kanorika.com';  //usually your domain

    /*** END VERSION 1.4 ***/


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use Eloquent's `query()` method, you can't do that, because `$db` must be instance of `Model` class. You should use Eloquent from the beginning or write your own `query()` method.